# IIS PHP 500 Error

Tags: php, iis-6

I have an application running in two places-- a development MAMP server on OS X, with PHP 5.3 and Apache, and a production IIS 6.0 server with PHP 5.3 as well.

The issue is, the application works fine on Apache. No errors, warnings, or anything.

But when I call a static function of a Utilities class I have on the IIS server, I get a 500 error. The problem is, the function is never called-- placing an "echo" at the beginning of the function does nothing, which tells me that it isn't the code *inside* of the function that's the issue... Other static functions of the class work fine.

Checking the log (`C:\Windows\temp\php-errors.log`) show nothing related to this issue, but it is properly logging other errors (unexpected characters and whatever else).

This is the function that is being called and the place where the script stops execution:

```
json_encode(Utilities::ContextifyToUser(Article::getArticlesInCollectionOfUser($user), $user);
```

Separating the `json_encode` and `getArticlesInCollection` show that they are both working and returning the correct values. It is the "Contextify" function that kills it.

This is the contextify function, as defined in a class called `Utilities`:

```
public static function ContextifyToUser($obj = array(), $user = null){
        if(is_null($user) || !is_array($obj)){
            return null;
        }

        foreach($obj as $key => $value){
            $obj[$key] = $value->contextifyToUser($user);
        }

        return $obj;
    }
```

As I mentioned previously, none of the code in the function is ever called. If I put an "echo 'hello'" after the function definition, it is never called.

Is it my code, or is this something weird with IIS? Considering this works perfectly in Apache, I think it's the latter...

I'd also like to point out that no errors are shown or logged, despite changing the display_errors INI and using `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. A 500 error is simply thrown and the script stops executing past that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was one of my functions inside one of the contextifyToUser was assuming a variable was a class, but it was null in cases. This didn't occur in my dev machine because it was using a different set of input data.

It. Hate. IIS. I'm still not sure why no errors were being logged and no exceptions or *anything* was being thrown.